# Can't figure out what to do for "call function until otherwise"

Tags: python, function, call

I'm taking an university course on python, I'm stuck on an assignment question that asks for the following:

Write a function iterate with the following arguments:

```
f: a function
start: a numeric starting value
tol: a numerical tolerance (default value 1e-6)
itmax: a maximum number of iterations (default value 1000)
```

Starting from the initial value, your function should keep repeating calls to the function (e.g. y=f(y)) until the absolute value of f(y)-y is less than tol or the number of iterations is equal to itmax.

To check if my code is correct, the following should be True

```
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.sqrt,1.01,tol=1e-4),[6, 1.0000777399813863]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0),[34, 0.7390855263619245]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0,tol=1e-8),[46, 0.7390851366465718]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0,itmax=5),[5, 0.7013687736227565]))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def approx_equal(f,start,tol,itmax):
    y=start
    tol=1e-6
    itmax=1000
        for i in range(itmax):
                y=f(y)
        while abs(f(y)-y) < tol or i==itmax:
                break
```

I'm not sure how to do the "repeat calls to the function until the absolute value of f(y)-y is less than tol or the number of iterations is equal to itmax.

Comment: It may help to think of "until" as "while not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is pretty close, but you have a couple of issues.  To pass a default value for a parameter, you need to do it in the first line of the definition statement.  The way you have it currently written, `tol` will **always** be `1e-6` and `itmax` will **always** be `1000`.

Also, you should add a check against the tolerance using `if`.  You can use either `break` or `return` if the difference is less than the tolerance.  `break` will break the `for` loop, but `return` will exit the function and give a value.

```
def approx_equal(f, start, tol=1e-6 ,itmax=1000):
    y = start
    for i in range(itmax):
        y_new = f(y)
        if abs(y_new-y) < tol:
            return y  # return the value when the next iteration is not needed
        else:
            y = y_new
```

Comment: You need to handle the case when the for loop completes without a tolerance match occurring.